# Sharepoint re-order item order in the list

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

In the list, I set-up "ID" column and "Title" column.

I added 10 items in the list, and I'm trying to put the 10th item between 1 and 2.
After my research, many people said I can't manually change ID number...
Is there a way to re-order the item?
deleting every items is the only answer?

Please help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ID column is an internal identity-like column. You cannot change the value. If you need a column that you can order by (and change), just create a new column called SortOrder or something. Then sort by that column.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old post, but I thought this might help someone who might be looking for an OOB answer. 
Go into your links list so that you see your List Tools, Items and List at the top.
Select Items.
There is a Change Item Order Icon in the Ribbon. This will allow you to renumber the Links in your list and change the order.

Answer (score 1):

You can manually change the items order if you create your list based on a link list definition. This kind of list allows you to re-order items as you require through a ribbon button. I use this workaround often.

Answer (score 0):

The ID Column is SharePoint inbuilt and you can not change the value of it.
for your solution either you need to delete all item and insert it again or as @Nigel Whatling say you have to add SortColumn

Answer (score 0):

Column Setting will only change the order in the SharePoint List.   To change the view order Use the Modify View Selector to adjust the way the fields are sorted.   Modify View is found on the ... next to Find and Item Box    or    If your in the site setting it is under View on the lower 3rd of the page

Answer (score 0):

I also got stuck with this and couldn't use the previous answers as I couldn't see the buttons they spoke of in the ribbon.

I went to **List** > **List Settings** in the ribbon. At the bottom of the list settings page I click on a **View** to edit it (or create new view). Unser the heading **Sort** you can change the column you wish to sort by and change from descending to ascending etc.

Answer (score -2):

Actually, if I understand the question, it was just what I was trying to accomplish and spent most of my morning working on.

1. Select the List.
2. From toolbar, select List under List Tools.
3. Click List Settings.
4. Below the listed columns, see Column Ordering
5. Modify "Position from Top" number and click OK at bottom.

Comment: the OP is asking to reorder the items, not the fields

Answer (score -2):

Updated steps:

1. Select the List.
2. From toolbar, select List under List Tools.
3. Click List Settings.
4. Above the Column list click on the "Item" link
5. At the bottom of the page select "Column Ordering"
6. Modify "Position from Top" number and click OK at bottom.

Comment: the OP is asking to reorder the items, not the fields